# $I_n=\int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}}dx$. Prove $n\cdot I_n=\sqrt{5}-4(n-1)I_{n-2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$I_n=\int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}}dx$$
Prove $$n\cdot I_n=\sqrt{5}-4(n-1)I_{n-2}$$
I can't figure this exercise. What I usually do with this kind of exercise is first trying to work with the equation so that it comes out to a difference(or sum) of integrals,   to then replace everything in the equation and the result would come out naturally afterwards.

$$n\cdot I_n=\sqrt{5}-4(n-1)I_{n-2}$$

Added $4(n-1)I_{n-2}$ to both sides

$$n\cdot I_n +4(n-1)I_{n-2} = \sqrt5$$

$$n\cdot I_n +4nI_{n-2}-4I_{n-2}=\sqrt5$$

$$n(I_n+4I_{n-2})-4I_{n-2}=\sqrt5$$

Added $4I_{n-2}$ to both sides

$$n(I_n+4I_{n-2})=\sqrt5+4I_{n-2}$$

Multiplied by $\frac{1}{n}$ both sides

$$I_n+4I_{n-2}=\frac{\sqrt5 +4I_{n-2}}{n}$$

Now I replace $I_n$ and $I_{n-2}$ in the left part of the equation to try and prove it is equal to the right part.

$$\int_0^1\bigg({\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}}dx+4\int_0^1{\frac{x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}}dx\bigg)$$

$$\int_0^1\bigg({\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}+4{\frac{x^{n-2}} {\sqrt{x^2+4}}}}\bigg)dx$$

$$\int_0^1\bigg({\frac{x^{n-2}(x^2+4)}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}}\bigg)dx$$
$$\int_0^1\bigg({x^{n-2}\sqrt{x^2+4}\bigg)}dx$$

At this point I think maybe I am doing something wrong. I could try a substitution $u=\sqrt{x^2+4}$ but then this is what I get:
$$\int{\sqrt{u^2-4}}^{n-3}u^2du$$ 
And now this really makes me think either I have made a mistake or this approach is way too difficult for me, at least in this case. How would you solve this exercise?

Comment: That was a limit and the answer involved the Squeeze Theorem, what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hnnt:

$$I_n=\int_0^1\dfrac{x^n+4x^{n-2}-4x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}dx=\int_0^1x^{n-2}\sqrt{x^2+4}dx-4I_{n-2}$$

Now
$$\int_0^1x^{n-2}\sqrt{x^2+4}dx=\sqrt{x^2+4}\cdot\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n-1}\big|_0^1-\int_0^1\dfrac{x^{n-1}\cdot2x}{(n-1)2\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\dfrac{\sqrt5}{n-1}-\dfrac{I_n}{n-1}$$

Comment: Alright, I don't think I would have ever come to this realization by myself. Thank you.

Comment: @labbattarcharjee : sorry, I realized only after posting that there was already your reply. Since yours has been accepted I leave mine just to show an alternative way for the reaching the same result

Answer (score 1):

$$
\eqalign{
  & I_{\,n}  = \int_0^1 {{{x^{\,n} } \over {\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + 4} }}dx}  = \int_0^1 {x^{\,n - 1} d\left( {\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + 4} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left. {x^{\,n - 1} \sqrt {x^{\,2}  + 4} \;} \right|_{\,0}^{\,1}  - \left( {n - 1} \right)\int_0^1 {x^{\,n - 2} \left( {\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + 4} } \right)dx}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt 5  - \left( {n - 1} \right)\int_0^1 {{{x^{\,n - 2} } \over {\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + 4} }}\left( {x^{\,2}  + 4} \right)dx}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt 5  - \left( {n - 1} \right)\int_0^1 {{{x^{\,n} } \over {\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + 4} }}dx}  - 4\left( {n - 1} \right)\int_0^1 {{{x^{\,n - 2} } \over {\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + 4} }}dx}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt 5  - \left( {n - 1} \right)I_{\,n}  - 4\left( {n - 1} \right)I_{\,n - 2}  \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

this is only hint you can try easily from this way(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZzdF.jpg)

Comment: I like this approach a lot more, seems easier to me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Every integral like this have been solved to many ways but if you are good at derivatives it is not difficult to solve

Comment: Can you type this out using mathjax? Your answer may be useful to someone in the future, your image would not support a search

Comment: @higgs can you type it and post it? Actually my phone is not good sorry..

Comment: No, I can't do that.

Comment: So if there is an easy way to type it tells it to me

Comment: Learn mathjax yourself.

Comment: I will try thank you